# Flot Time Axis Range

Tags: jquery, flot, timestamp

How can I set the options in a flot graph so that it displays data for only the current day?  I have the timestamps and formatting working, but I'm not sure how to make it show only the current day (so the axis is continually updating to the current day).

EDIT:

Here is a snippet of the code that I'm currently using:

```
// mode specific options
                    tickDecimals: null, // no. of decimals, null means auto
                    tickSize: null, // number or [number, "unit"]
                    minTickSize: [1, "hour"], // number or [number, "unit"]
                    monthNames: null, // list of names of months
                    timeformat: "%H:%I",
                    twelveHourClock: "12" // 12 or 24 time in time mode
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the xaxis min/max options before calling plot(). Time1 is milliseconds of a day's first 00:00:00 hour and Time2 is the day's 23:00:00 hour.

```
data: [.....],
...    
xaxis{ min: Time1, max: Time2}
```